# Concatenating Month and Year of dates to order them by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an issue that I think I am overthinking. I have a SQL view that I import to PowerBI, and I want to use this to order a graph I am building. The part I am ordering on and having issues with is the date part column:

```sql
select
    Ticket_ClientName, count(Ticket_ClientName) as DisplayNameCount,
    concat( datepart(month, cast(t.ticket_opendate as date)),
            datepart(year, cast(t.ticket_opendate as date))) as OpenDate,
    datename(month, cast(t.ticket_opendate as date)) as Month_Name
from 
    dbo.Ticket t
where 
    CAST(t.ticket_opendate as date) >= '02/01/2021'
    and t.Ticket_ClientName is not null
    and Ticket_DisplayId not like 'EH%'
group by
    ticket_ClientName,
    concat( datepart(month, cast(t.ticket_opendate as date)),
            datepart(year, cast(t.ticket_opendate as date))),
    datename(month, cast(t.ticket_opendate as date))
```

The issue I am going to face is when the year rolls over, as the months of October to December will always remain as the latest month, due to them being the highest number, does anyone have a way to get around this?
I apologise in advance if I am overthinking this.

Comment: Seems like the problem is you are formatting your data in the SQL, rather than the reporting layer; if you leave them as a strongly type data type, you don't have this issue.

Comment: Also some recommended reading: [Cast to date is sargable but is it a good idea?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea). Though why you're casting `t.ticket_opendate` to a `date` in the `WHERE` doesn't *really* make sense unless `t.ticket_opendate` isn't a date and time data type; but then, by definition, it *isn't* a date.

Comment: If you want to order by these two date parts then put the year first `202108` and make sure the month has two digits.

Comment: @Larnu The reason I have the Where clause is because that is when we have the most reliable data from, before that we have some data which isn't accurate

Comment: That doesn't explain why you are casting `ticket_opendate` to a `date` @cai120 . Both `2021-01-02` and `2021-01-02 11:00:00` are `>= '20210102'`. The `CAST` just harms performance.

Comment: @Larnu currently my data set is very small, I appreciate your concern however the performance won't be affected

Comment: why not create a contrived date out of those values in a separate column and order off of it?

Answer (score 1):

**You can group and order by `EOMONTH`,** which returns the last day of that month.

```sql
select
    Ticket_ClientName,
    count(Ticket_ClientName) as DisplayNameCount,
    FORMAT(EOMONTH(t.ticket_opendate), 'MMyyyy') as OpenDate,
    datename(month, EOMONTH(t.ticket_opendate)) as Month_Name
from 
    dbo.Ticket t
where 
    t.ticket_opendate >= '20210102'
    and t.Ticket_ClientName is not null
    and Ticket_DisplayId not like 'EH%'
group by
    ticket_ClientName,
    EOMONTH(t.ticket_opendate)
order by
    EOMONTH(t.ticket_opendate);
```